# Cannot find name FileReader Error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I am developing an application in angular 2 using visual studio code 1.10.1

I get the error notified but the code is working fine.[image]

How to clear off this error

Comment: perhaps you need to import it?

Comment: I assume FileReader is core js command